# PPTP VPN Error 807 using OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-7, openvpn, pptp

Am struggling with the Windows error 807 when connecting to PPTP VPN using OpenVPN to a Windows Server 2012.

Am not sure where the problem lies and tried so many things in vain.

I should not need to modify any settings in my router because of OpenVPN where the service has started successfully on the server machine.

Am using Portmap.io where I got a domain:port that forwards traffic to 1723 on the server the OpenVPN service is running.

I can connect to the VPN server locally on LAN but not through the OpenVPN tunnel however.  SSTP VPN works but is too slow that is why am testing PPTP.

Kindly advise.